# Different OS built in crypto API

Tags: android, ios, linux, macos, cryptography

I need to investigate functional abilities of OS built in crypt API. Creating self-signed certificate, centralized protected key store and making PKCS7 signature are interested me. For this purposes i am going to use RSA or DSA algorithms only. My target OSes are Windows, Linux, OSX, iOS, Android and Windows RT. After lots of googling at this time I have found some answers which I've aggregated in the following table:

---

Windows: Store(+) Cert(+) Sign(+)

Linux: Store(-) Cert(-) Sign(-)

OSX: Store(+) Cert(na) Sign(na)

Windows RT: Store(na) Cert(na) Sign(na)

Android: Store(+) Cert(-) Sign(-)

iOS: Store(+) Cert(-) Sign(-)

---

I need help with na items and I appreciate if somebody checks my results.

- Windows - CAPICom all functionality
- Linux - only kernel mode and symmetric cipher
- Android - Java API, main functionality of store and raw signing, I
  also know that there is exists built in OpenSSL which has cert and
  sign functionality, but this library is "not stable" by Android
  terminology, so using it is not true way.
- iOS - security sub System, full functionality of store and raw
  signing
- OSX - security sub System, full functionality of store, I know that
  there is exists built in tools for creating certificates, but I need
  programmatic version of this functionality and I hope that PCKS7 also supported
- Windows RT - I suppose that it should be CAPICom or CNG, but I
  haven't found any prove information about RT version

Answer (score 1):

I can only comment for Linux.

If you are looking at cryptography within the kernel, indeed it is fairly limited. However, no application uses crypto from the kernel, but all apps use crypto from packages like `libgcrypt`, `gnutls` or `nettle`.

For key management, look into `keyutils` and `gnome-keyring`.

Comment: *Few* applications use crypto from the kernel, but most at least depend on the random number generator, arguably the most important part for an application, as they cannot generate secure randoms without good seeding.